# How to sum find the average of several datetime

Tags: python, datetime, average

I am wondering how to find the average of the several datetimes.
For example, I have the following datetime list:

```
a=[datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 14), datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 15), datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 16), datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 17)]
```

When I trying to add them up directly, it tells me that there is a

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'`

Not sure what is the correct way of doing this.

Very appreciated if you could help me out!

Thank you!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. What exactly is the average of a set of date time’s? Maybe you want the median time? Or mean time? I don’t think trying to “average” these values is possible nor would it give you any valuable data.. Please clarify with examples.

Comment: @Lkabo: good question; given these datetimes are the independent variable of a time series with irregular sampling frequency and you want e.g. an hourly average that *reflects* the irregularities in sampling frequency - then I imagine this could make sense. I'd prefer binning though in such a case, combined with an output of the error of the mean for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically, you can calculate the "average" of your datetimes by casting their mean timestamp (UNIX time) to a new datetime object:

```
import datetime

l = [datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 14), 
     datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 15),
     datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 16), 
     datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 17)]

middle = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sum(d.timestamp() for d in l)/len(l))

# middle
# datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 14, 0, 15, 30)
```